# Defining syles in video shadow DOM(s)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Any suggestions on how to append the style of an input "range" element when it is a shadow of the HTML 5 video element. From my understanding the normal method would be as in example 1. if you were styling the track.

What I would hope to achieve is color 1. is to the left of the thumb showing complete, with color 2 to the right to show pending video.

Example 1.

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
width: 300px;
height: 5px;
background: #ddd;
border: none;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

The method to target a video shadow DOM would normally be a a prefix of video:: however, the following dosen't work any pointers appreciated.

```
video::input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
width: 300px;
height: 5px;
background: #ddd;
border: none;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Any solutions either CSS, HTML, or pure Javascript appreciated...

Comment: this ? https://jsfiddle.net/kbb39xt7/ check on chrome

Comment: How would you create a different color either side of the thumb?

Answer (score 0):

Building off Vitorino's fiddle, the closest workaround I could come up with was to 1) add a `timeupdate` event listener that calculated the percentage of video played, then 2) set that percentage as a background with multiple gradients by updating the CSS in a `<style>` element, like so:

HTML:

```
<style id="ugh"></style>
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg"> Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

JS:

```
var run = 0;
var ss = document.getElementById("ugh");
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    run = this.currentTime / this.duration * 100;
    ss.textContent = 'video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline { background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, red ' + run + '%, yellow ' + run + '%, yellow 100%);'
});
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbb39xt7/19/)

However, this doesn't access the buffer amount (the darker gray on the default slider), and the circle is still blue. I couldn't quickly figure out a way to change its color, but I could turn it into a gray box by adding:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```